# TypeError: areatriangle() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given

Tags: python, math, typeerror

Im new to coding and im trying to learn python on coursera and im having issues with this one exercise

Exercise:
Write a function `def areatriangle(b, h):` to compute the area
of a triangle: formula is `area = .5 * b * h`.
Output should look like:
The area of a triangle of base 3 and height 5 is 7.5

You can test your function by executing the following code:

```py
#%%
# The following will test areatriangle()
areatriangle(3,5)
areatriangle(2,20)
#%%
```

But whenever i try to run them in the console i get the error message

```
TypeError: areatriangle() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

what should i do

Comment: Show us more of the relevant code, especially your definition of a areatriangle function.

Comment: You can code this function in just 2 lines (one if you use compact syntax), I'm sure you can do it ;)

Answer (score 1):

> TypeError: areatriangle() takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given

This tells us that the areatriangle() method takes no input parameters.

> areatriangle(3,5)

You have given two arguments (breadth and height). Now Python has no idea what to do with them and raises an error.

You can use this:

```py
def areatriangle(breadth, height):
    area = .5 * breadth * height
    return area # or you can do: return f"The area of a triangle of base {breadth} and height {height} is {area}"


area = areatriangle(3, 5)
print(area)
```